# Delphi Setting bit Flags

Tags: delphi, bitflags

a little out of my depth here.

I am using a component that has some Flags in the Object Inspector ...

```
FCOPY
  Flags
    flShowProgress
    flConfirmation
```

I need to change flShowProgess depending on the size of a file being copied.

```
if FileSize(aFilename) > 500000 then 
  FCOPY.Flags.flShowProgress:=True else
  FCOPY.Flags.flShowProgress:=False;
```

Obviously that does not compile. I have done a bunch of searching to find some examples but I really don't know the exact terms I need to use to find how to do this.

Could someone please show me how to do what I need with the Flags to turn on the flShowProgress only for files larger than 5M and then off again for the smaller files?

Thank you.

Comment: Please show the type definitions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming flags is a property of type set.

```
    if FileSize(aFilename) > 5000000 then  // bytes!
      FCOPY.Flags:=FCOPY.Flags+[flShowProgress]
    else
      FCOPY.Flags:=FCOPY.Flags-[flShowProgress]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the square brackets. I almost had it correct after about 20 different tries, but the square brackets are the key. Thank you very much.

Comment: They change an element (enum) to a set. (of enum). Always keep clear in your mind what type something is. It is the key to understanding typed languages.